# deploying flask app to heroku error

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have pushed this particular app so many times to heroku without any issues until today when it gave me errors like this

```
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 2.49 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.5.1
remote:  !     Requested runtime (python-3.5.1) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to serene-temple-30062.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/serene-temple-30062.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/serene-temple-30062.git'
```

Then i changed the runtime.txt to python-3.6.0 since that was the supported runtime now i get errors like this

```
remote:          Found existing installation: appdirs 1.4.3
remote:            Uninstalling appdirs-1.4.3:
remote:              Successfully uninstalled appdirs-1.4.3
remote:          Rolling back uninstall of appdirs
remote:        Exception:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2813, in _dep_ma
p
remote:            return self.__dep_map
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2624, in __getat
tr__
remote:            raise AttributeError(attr)
remote:        AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map
remote:
remote:        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
remote:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2804, in _parsed
_pkg_info
remote:            return self._pkg_info
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2624, in __getat
tr__
remote:            raise AttributeError(attr)
remote:        AttributeError: _pkg_info
remote:
remote:        During handling of the above exception, another exception    occurred:
remote:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
remote:            status = self.run(options, args)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
remote:            prefix=options.prefix_path,
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
remote:            **kwargs
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
remote:            self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel
_files
remote:            isolated=self.isolated,
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 247, in move_wheel_files
remote:            prefix=prefix,
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/locations.py", line 140, in distutils_scheme
remote:            d = Distribution(dist_args)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 320, in __init__
remote:            _Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
remote:          File  "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 281, in __init__
remote:            self.finalize_options()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 386, in finalize_option
s
remote:            ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in require

remote:            items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 862, in resolve
remote:            new_requirements = dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1]
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2568, in require
s
remote:            dm = self._dep_map
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2815, in _dep_ma
p
remote:            self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2824, in _comput
e_dependencies
remote:            for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2806, in _parsed
_pkg_info
remote:            metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1468, in get_met
adata
remote:            value = self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1577, in _get
remote:            with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
remote:        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  '/tmp/build_d5216bcdf3f42398e57859a9302dd93f/.her
oku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appdirs-1.4.3.dist-info/METADATA'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to serene-temple-30062.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/serene-temple-30062.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/serene-temple-30062.git'
```

Please any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: can you look into this ! 
[link] https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse/issues/8

Comment: Am looking into that right thanks for the response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced this issue recently. This seems to be an issue particularly with appdirs. I've resolved this issue by just simply upgrading appdirs, updating my requirements.txt and then redeploying to heroku.

```
pip install appdirs --upgrade
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: Ah I didn't post an update on my progress but you are right that was exactly what I did but I kind of just changed the requirements,txt file to appdirs 1.4.3 not 1.4.2 but thank you for your response I will accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for this, fixed my problem. Same versions as the comment above - 1.4.2 had a problem, 1.4.3 fixed it.