# Heroku Deploying App

Tags: python, git, heroku, flask

I have a problem with delpoying my webapp to heroku. A year ago other users had a similar problem: [deploying flask app to heroku error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942036/deploying-flask-app-to-heroku-error) However, the offered solution does not work for me. Any other ideas? Would really appreciate help.
Thanks upfront.

Here is my log:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing python-3.6.5
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Exception:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
           status = self.run(options, args)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 312, in run
           wheel_cache
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 295, in populate_requirement_set
           wheel_cache=wheel_cache):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 93, in parse_requirements
           for req in req_iter:
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 158, in process_line
           isolated=isolated, options=req_options, wheel_cache=wheel_cache
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 195, in from_line
           if (os.path.isdir(p) and
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 42, in isdir
           st = os.stat(s)
       ValueError: embedded null byte
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: I have also encountered similar errors while deploying my Django app. I created a Procfile and that solved my problem. I don't know if it will work for flask. Just try.

Comment: Thank you. I have the Procfile. And I have another app running on heroku. I don´t find the difference! Cannot explain whats wrong...

Comment: Even I went through the same situation. And it was solved when I added something extra to my Procfile. Content of my procfile is :
`web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi web: gunicorn myproject:myapp
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have embedded null byte (`\x00`) somewhere in `requirements.txt`.